# In python,I want to use \b to backspace but it shows 0x08,how to fix this problem

Tags: python-3.x, windows, sublimetext3

```
print("a\bc", end="", flush=True)
#I hope the out put is c rather than a0x08c
```

[the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptQi3.png)

Comment: Answer is terminal-specific.  The code shown works at a cmd.exe prompt.  It is a sublime text problem not a Python problem.

Comment: Yep, can confirm it works on a bash terminal emulator too. Also, you should include the output as text in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried out your code it works perfectly fine for me, it printed https://i.stack.imgur.com/bA97f.png

I'm guessing something wrong with the editor or python itself, but not really sure.

you can once try the code in IDLE, Jupyter Notebook / Lab, or Terminal.